# Is it time to start adding moderators?

Tags: discussion

Since we're about two weeks into the public beta now, I would think that it would be time to start considering adding more moderators (right now, I believe Anna is the only moderator, and she's with SE, as opposed to being a member-moderator.

Is it time to begin the process of adding [*pro tempore* moderators](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/)? I think it would help improve board "flow", and keep things moving in a more productive direction.

Comment: I think we could stand to start adding mods, yes

Comment: Can you add pro-tempore moderators to a graduated site?  I thought SE required a moderator election.

Comment: No, graduated sites require elections. However, this post was written, as stated, when the site was still in public beta.

Answer (score 7):

**Yes**. This community, while still small, has had it's share of low-quality questions and trolls, and internal moderators could handle that sort of stuff much quicker than outside.

Also, people here so far have been very forthcoming with discussions, and if a moderator acted in a way which upset the community, I have faith that the community would discuss it in meta in a healthy way, and if necessary the mod would reverse the action. We've got a good crowd here :)

Answer (score 3):

I agree, there has been recently several low quality posts, where it seemed that the intention was just to ask as many questions as possible, without taking the time to address the comments and concerns on previous posts. There has also been a spam yesterday, but the SE moderators removed it quite quickly.

And as eykanal mentioned, I think that if there were any problem, the community would easily sort it out on the meta.